# Why do I keep getting this error from amplify " The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I keep receiving this error "An error occurred during the push operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." even though my keys are valid and they're properly set up from the environment. I cant get any pictures

This is a picture of my iam access keys :

https://res.cloudinary.com/di449masi/image/upload/v1642705423/IMG_20220120_140148_wnny3l.jpg

This is what it says on my terminal when i check the credentials:

https://res.cloudinary.com/di449masi/image/upload/v1642705918/IMG_20220120_141005_afbatk.jpg

Comment: Do you have configured environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)?

Comment: Yes and the keys are active

Comment: Those env vars are the same you have configured on .aws config file?

Comment: I dont see an aws config file anywhere but i ran the command "aws configure" put in the iam user and it still didnt work

Comment: Ok, please run this command: aws sts get-caller-identity and validate that the user it returns is the one that you want

Comment: I ran it earlier it seems like it does but im not too sure what im seeing i just know its returning the right user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241262/discussion-between-tg-marcus-and-omar-rosadio).